# Action after file selected

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working in ember (and js in general) for pretty much the first time.

Here's the scenario: there is a "choose file" button. The standard file selection button has been hidden and replaced with a custom button. A user clicks the button, a file selection window appears, the user selects their file, and clicks 'ok'. Because the default button has been hidden, I need to indicate to the user that a file has been selected. I want to display a message indicating this.

In `template.hbs` I have something like

```
<button class="outline-only inline-block" id="my_file_button" {{action 'clickButton' 'my_file'}}>
   {{fa-icon icon="mouse-pointer"}} Choose file
</button>
<input type="file" id="my_file" name="my_file"> <!-- this is set to display: none in css file -->
{{#if my_file_button_clicked}}
  {{fa-icon icon="check-circle"}} File selected
{{/if}}
```

in `component.js` I've defined as part of `actions`:

```
clickButton(button) {
  let self = this;
  jquery('#'+button).click();
  self.set(button+'_button_clicked', true);
}
```

What this does is cause the "file selected" message to be displayed as soon as the user clicks the "choose file" button, whether they complete the file selection or click 'cancel'. How can I make it so the message does not display until a completed, successful selection has been made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind an action to the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) of the file input. In ember.js you are doing it like this:

```
<input type="file" id="my_file" name="my_file" onchange={{action 'fileChanged'}}>
```

The event is passed to the action as an argument. It contains a reference to the selected file via a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). You could use that one to check if the user has selected a file or not. If the user has selected a file, you could store a reference to it in a variable. A primitive action would look like this:

```
Component.extends({
  filesSelected: null, 

  actions: {
    fileChanged(event) {
      let files = event.target.files;
      this.set('filesSelected', files);
    }
  }
});
```

You could use that variable to show the icon only if a file has been selected:

```
{{#if filesSelected.length}}
  {{fa-icon icon="check-circle"}} File selected
{{/if}}
```

Please note that there are already some Ember addons providing the functionality you are trying to implement. I would recommend to check out the file upload category on Ember Observer: https://www.emberobserver.com/categories/file-upload